# Replicating a data.frame according to a vector of lengths`

Tags: r, dataframe, replication

I have a `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(1)
short.df <- data.frame(id=letters[1:10],name=LETTERS[1:10])
```

And I want to replicate each row by a number of times given by a vector whose length equals `nrow(short.df)`:

```
lengths <- c(sample(10000,10,replace=F))
```

This takes too long for my real data size:

```
long.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:length(lengths),function(x) data.frame(id=rep(short.df$id,lengths[x]),name=rep(short.df$name[x],lengths[x]))))
```

Any way to do it faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replicate the rows by using `rep()` in the `i` argument of `[.data.frame`.

```
long.df <- short.df[rep(1:nrow(short.df), lengths), ]
```

Check:

```
identical(nrow(long.df), sum(lengths))
# [1] TRUE
```

The new row names may not be desirable, but those are easy to change.